# Commerce Kickstart 2 Need Rule To Apply Sales Tax To Shipping

Tags: commerce

I need a Rule to apply sales tax to shipping on a sales order.

I tried the following code (borrowed from here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2307695) and it doesn't work for me:

```
{ "rules_apply_sales_tax_to_shipping" : {
"LABEL" : "Apply sales tax to shipping",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"WEIGHT" : "5",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"REQUIRES" : [ "commerce_tax", "commerce_shipping" ],
"ON" : { "commerce_shipping_calculate_rate" : [] },
"DO" : [
{ "commerce_tax_calculate_by_type" : {
"commerce_line_item" : [ "commerce_line_item" ],
"tax_type_name" : "sales_tax"
}
}
]
}
}
```

Maybe there is a typo? There are only two tax_types on our site, sales_tax and VAT so I don't think so.

Do I need to add this as an Action onto our Sales Tax? I don't see how to do this... this does not appear in the drop down list of available Actions.

Comment: Do you have any conditions on the Rules component for the taxes in question?

Comment: No. At the risk of sounding stupid (again). There are no conditions in the Rule for Calculate Sales Tax on the product line items. Shouldn't I simply be able to clone -that- rule (CST) but point it to line items of type 'shipping'? I just don't know how to do it. FWIW: I can't figure out for the life of me how to address the variables through the UI. TIA --JC

Answer (score 0):

don't know if you solved this yet (hope so). The trick is to set your tax rate and THEN apply is a calculation rule to shipping. Not the most intuitive way to do it, but it works.